# encrypt singly url by .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla2.5

In our site , if we keep mouse on button , it will show url on status bar .

like URL : `https://XXX.singly.com/one/XXXXXX`

but i want hide this url in status bar with another name .

for ex.URL : `https://YYY.ZZZZ.com/AAAAAAAA`
if it is possible .Please help me

OR , Is there any way to hide the url totally .

Thanks,
Srinivas

How can i write below url

https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=274278176032919&skip_api_login=1&display=page&cancel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.singly.com%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fauth%2Fc8f1b1b37732c352634362adf8d945ea%************

to

https://www.facebook.com/login.php/api_key/display

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of great SEF Components out there - [SEF type extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/sef)

Some of those may be able to give you some of the flexibility you're looking for.  I'm sure it's possible to do it other ways - but you may want to check some of those first instead of trying to reinvent the wheel if they will do what you want.